# Why does my plot made by 'pgfplots' come out empty?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Here is my code -

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[yticklabels=\empty, xticklabels=\empty]
      
        \addplot 
        % add a plot from table; you select the columns by using the actual name in
        % the .csv file (on top)
        table[x = x, y = z][col sep = “white space”] {abc.txt}; 
        \legend{Plot}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Plots}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

The data is in the form of a txt file and here are the top 4 rows -

```
x y
 60 -3131.84
 51 -6275.58
 59 -4578.68
 42 -9346.83
```

Comment: Haven't tested anything,  but why the `col sep=comma` when the file uses spaces as column separator?

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT. I made the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems with

```
table[x = x, y = z][col sep = “white space”] {abc.txt};
```

First off, I get an error saying

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file '[' in 'search path=.'
```

What happens there is that when `pgfplots` reaches the end of the first bracket pair, the next thing should be a filename (or macro for a loaded table). But the next thing it sees is the second bracket, so you get the above error. If you need to specify the `col sep`, do it in the same brackets as where you specify the column.

Second, there is no `white space` value for the `col sep` key. There is one called `space`, but that is the default, so you don't actually need to specify it. To sum up these first two points, use either

```
table[x = x, y = z, col sep=space]
```

or

```
table[x = x, y = z]
```

Finally, having fixed the above, I get the error

```
Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column 'z' from table
```

which points to the minor mistake of having `table[x=x, y=z]`, while the column name actually used in the file is `y`. I.e., you need `table[x=x, y=y]`.

Comment: By the way, if you don't specify the columns, `pgfplots` will use the first column for the x-values and the second column for the y-values, so in your case you could just do `\addplot table{abc.txt};`